# What is a fast and simple way to add extra space to the existing EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, system-administration

Is there a fast and simplest way to add additional space on a  running EC2 instance. I am a non-sysadmin guy so finding difficult whatever I found in the aws documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is to allocate a new EBS volume and attach it to your running instance, so for example, in Windows it might show up as a "D" drive in addition to the "C" drive the machine already has.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSVolumes.html

Comment: If you want to maintain your data on a single drive, you can also take a snapshot of that drive and create a new (larger) EBS drive from that snapshot.

Comment: Cool! so this worked, I was able to maintain the single drive by creating the snapshot